# Checking all possible expressions that equal a certain number given 4 integers?

Tags: java

Hi everyone I would really appreciate any help with my program. In this program I have to ask the user to input 4 integers and I have to output one possible expression (out of many) that will equal 24. Also if there is no such solution I have to tell the user. So far this is what I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game24 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter 4 numbers and hit enter after each number: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String num1 = input.nextLine();
        String num2 = input.nextLine();
        String num3 = input.nextLine();
        String num4 = input.nextLine();
        StringPermutation("", num1 + "+" + num2 + "*" + num3 + "/" + num4 + "(" + ")");
    }

    public static String StringPermutation(String x, String y) {
        double expression = 0;
        int count = 0;

        if (y.length() <= 1) {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < y.length(); i++) {
                    String p = y.substring(0, i) + y.substring(i + 1);
                    expression = Double.parseDouble(StringPermutation(x + y.charAt(i), p));
                }

                if (y.length() <= 1 && expression == 24) {
                    do {
                        count++;
                        System.out.println(x + y);
                    } while (count < 1);
                }

                //if (y.length() <= 1 && expression != 24) {
                //    System.out.print("No solution");
                //}
            } catch (Exception e) {}

        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < y.length(); i++) {
                String p = y.substring(0, i) + y.substring(i + 1);
                StringPermutation(x + y.charAt(i), p);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is that I will get all permutations of the users input as a string. Then parse the string to a double and check all possible permutations to see if they equal 24 and if they do I output the expression as a string. However, this isn't working for me; when I run the program nothing shows up. Also, if I uncomment the commented part it doesn't display anything.

Comment: And here comes the flood of inevitable "use this: <code dump>" answers.

Comment: its just `input.nextLine();` the enter code here part is prob just formatting problem

Comment: Oh I'm sorry it's supposed to say String num1 = input.nextLine();

Comment: you never return anything other than the empty string so `Double.parseDouble(StringPermutation(x + y.charAt(i), p))` would always read as `Double.parseDouble("")`.

Comment: But it doesn't reach the return statement until all the permutations are finished though right?

Comment: There are so many issues here that I'm not sure how to answer it without the 'use this: <code dump>' that Jason mentions. Which wouldn't teach you much at all (assuming that's what you are after). If you would like us to give you some high level pointers about how to go about solving this then I'd be happy to do that.

Comment: Yes please I want to learn how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Here are some design hints that might help you get started:

1. Your current design of converting to a string and then testing permutations is poor. It is hard to understand and error prone. A better approach would be to build the expression string as you calculate the result of the expression.
2. A general form for a recursive method that builds a list of solutions is as follows:

   List solutions = new ArrayList<>(); 
   test(partialSolution, startingContext);

   private void test(Solution currentSolution, Context currentContext) {
       if (currentContext.isNotEmpty()) {
           for (each step) {
               test(currentSolution.add(step), currentContext.remove(step));
           }
       } else if (currentSolution.isSuccessful()) {
           solutions.add(currentSolution);
       } 
   }
3. In your case each 'step' involves 2 dimensions of permutations. The first dimension is to try all remaining operands. An easy way to do this without creating multiple arrays is to always use the first operand and then switch it with successive array members. The second dimension is each of the operators (* + - /). The simplest thing here is to just have 4 invocations of test. A more complete abstraction would be to put the operators in a separate enum but that's probably overkill for your situation.

So here's some partial code to get you started

```
class Expressions {
    private final Set<String> validExpressions = new TreeSet<>();

    public Expressions(int expectedResult, int... operands) {
        test("" + operands[0], operands[0], Arrays.copyOfRange(operands, 1, operands.length);
    }

    private void test(String currentExpression, int currentResult, int... operands) {
        if (operands.length > 0) {
            ...
        } else if (currentResult == result) {
             validExpressions.add(expression + " = " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason the recursive method code isn't formatting properly even though it's indented. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.